Probability Question: Not sure why approach incorrect
This appears to be a common type of question: A & B are alternately picking balls from a bag without replacement. The bag has $k$ black balls and 1 red ball. The winner is the one who picks the red ball. Who is more likely to win, the one who starts first, or second?
I tried to calculate $P($win|go first$) = p$
$P($win|go first$) = p = \frac{1}{k+1} + \frac{k}{k+1}\left(1-p\right)$
Here, the first term represents the likelihood of me ending the game with my first pick. The second term is $P($don't get red on first pick$)\cdot P($win after first pick$)$
$P($win after first pick$) = 1-p$ because it's now the opponent's turn, and the situation is such that we are starting the game from scratch, and the opponent is going first. But this yields the wrong answer for $p$.
This yields the wrong expression for $p$. I definitely can make an intuitive argument that we should choose to go first. But I also want to prove it analytically. Could you help me understand where I went wrong in trying to determine an expression for $p$?

Your analysis is wrong because after Player $1$ picks, you're not starting the game from scratch.  Because $1$ black ball has now been removed from the bag, $k$ has decreased by $1$ so Player $2$'s probability of winning has changed.
You can reach the correct answer via a symmetry argument.  Don't terminate the game.  Just use the successive picks to define an arrangement of the $k+1$ balls.  Player $1$ wins if the red ball is in an odd position, whereas Player $2$ wins if the red ball is in an even position.
Thus, if $k$ is odd, each player's probability of winning is $\frac 12$.  If $k=2n$ is even, then Player $1$'s probability of winning is $\frac {n+1}{2n+1}$.

Your approach seems to make the error of not taking into account the fact that the probabilities will depend on the number$~k$. To see that this must be the case, just consider the cases$~k=0$ (where the first player is certain to win) and $k=1$ (where both sides have equal chances of winning).
